# detect if file descriptor is socket in solaris 11.0 and extract ip address

Tags: c, linux, solaris, netstat

In Solaris, I need to get IP address a specific process is using (sshd session), I have his ID.
How do they do it on linux ? After reading netstat.c source, this is the flow:
Iterate the process file descriptors, located at /proc/ProcessId/fd/,
If iterated file descriptor is a socket, they readlink, open and finally read the file descriptor.

So in solaris, I can detect the socket file descriptor of the process.

```
int fd=NULL;
struct dirent *dentp;
while ((dentp = readdir(dirp)) != NULL) { //iterate file descriptors
   fd = atoi(dentp->d_name);
   struct stat statb;
   char temp_dir_path [100];
   if (stat(temp_dir_path, &statb) != -1)
   {
       if (S_ISSOCK(statb.st_mode))
       {
         //What to do here ?? temp_dir_path is /proc/12345/fd/4
```

I saw there are methods like getpeername(..),getsockname(..) they receive as param the file descriptor of the **current context process**, I want to read file descriptor for another process.
Can I open the file descriptor and cast it to struct sockaddr_in ?

The socket file descriptor structure is different between linux and solaris.. I guess i need to do whatever they do in pfiles / lsof

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I saw there are methods like getpeername(..),getsockname(..) they receive as param the file descriptor of the current context process, I want to read file descriptor for another process.
>   Can I open the file descriptor and cast it to struct sockaddr_in ?

No.  You can `open()` it and use the file descriptor `open()` returns and try using `getpeername()` and `getsockname()` on the file descriptor you get.  It might even work.

You'll probably be better served by using the method `pfiles` uses.  [Per the `pfiles` man page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E86824_01/html/E54763/pfiles-1.html#scrolltoc):

> pfiles
>
> Report `fstat(2)` and `fcntl(2)` information for all open files in
>   each process. **For network endpoints, the local (and peer if
>   connected) address information is also provided.** For sockets, the
>   socket type, socket options and send and receive buffer sizes are also
>   provided. In addition, a path to the file is reported if the
>   information is available from /proc/pid/path. This is not necessarily
>   the same name used to open the file. See proc(4) for more information.

The `pfiles` source code can be found at http://src.illumos.org/source/xref/illumos-gate/usr/src/cmd/ptools/pfiles/pfiles.c

Solaris provides a `libproc` interface library that does what you need.  `pfiles` uses that - the library provides calls such as [`pr_getpeername()`](http://illumos.org/man/3proc/pr_getpeername) and [`pr_getsockname()`](http://illumos.org/man/3proc/pr_getsockname). You can see the implementations in http://src.illumos.org/source/xref/illumos-gate/usr/src/lib/libproc/common/pr_getsockname.c

Note that there are actual system calls to get what you need directly from the kernel.

The **Open**Solaris man pages for the `libproc` library can be found at http://illumos.org/man/3proc/all  They are likely to be substantially similar to the Solaris 11 `libproc` implementation.

To use these tools, you have to be really careful.  From [the `Pgrab` man page for the function used to grab a process](http://illumos.org/man/3proc/Pgrab):

> Grabbing a process is a destructive action. Stopping a process stops
>   execution of all its threads. The impact of stopping a process depends
>   on the purpose of that process. For example, if one stops a process
>   that's primarily doing computation, then its computation is delayed
>   the entire time that it is stopped. However, if instead this is an
>   active TCP server, then the accept backlog may fill causing connection
>   errors and potentially connection time out errors.

There are options to not stop the grabbed process, and to grab it read-only.

Comment: Thank i will check tomorrow at work.. When I tried open() the file descriptor as root, from child process of the target process, it returned -1

Comment: The *easy* solution is something like `popen( "pfiles 1234", "r);` and just parse the output. That has the advantage of not being dependent on undocumented or sparsely documented Solaris internal implementations at the cost of performance.

Comment: This I can do from batch script also.. but its not good since pfiles pause the process while inspecting it. I wish to avoid the pause since I need a quick read only..

Comment: I fail to find libproc.h headers and additional files.. What do i need to add to machine ? a certain package ?

Comment: @ilansch It might only be in OpenSolaris distributions. It wouldn't surprise me to find out that Oracle isn't as willing to share Solaris internals as Sun was.

Comment: I understand they inject a method getpeername to the target process. This what pfiles does. I can inject the method also?